# TimeOut exception while calling two times a stored procedure in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a function which called when i click item in gridview.
That function calls a stored procodure.The function is,

```
void fp_GetMRVByItem(int ItemID)
    {
        DTMRVdetails = null;
        MIVP.ItemID = ItemID;
        MIVP.SubCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(hfSubCategory.Value); //SubCategoryID;
        MIVP.MIVTypeID = Convert.ToInt16(hfMIVTypeID.Value);
        if (hfMIVTypeID.Value == "2")
        {
            if (gvMIVMRV.Rows.Count > 0 && DTMIVMRV.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MIVP.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(DTMIVMRV.Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString());
                MIVP.JobOrderID = Convert.ToInt32(DTMIVMRV.Rows[0]["JobOrderID"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MIVP.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(hfCustomerID.Value);
                MIVP.JobOrderID = Convert.ToInt32(hfJobOrderID.Value);
            }
            DTMRVdetails = MIVBLL.MRVGridLoad(MIVP);//This call works perfectly.But when i moved flow moved into
            // the following if I reset values to CustomerID,JobOrderID and again call the SP.Here I get
            // the exception
            //Timeout expired.The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
            if (DTMRVdetails.Rows.Count == 0 && gvMIVMRV.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MIVP.CustomerID = -1;
                MIVP.JobOrderID = -1;
                DTMRVdetails = MIVBLL.MRVGridLoad(MIVP);//Timeout expired.The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

            }
            fp_GridViewSource(gvMRVdetails, DTMRVdetails);

        }
        else
        {
            MIVP.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(hfCustomerID.Value);
            MIVP.JobOrderID = Convert.ToInt32(hfJobOrderID.Value);
            //if (gvMRVdetails.Rows.Count > 0)
            //    DTMRVdetails.Merge(MIVBLL.MRVGridLoad(MIVP), false, MissingSc6hemaAction.Ignore);
            //else
            DTMRVdetails = MIVBLL.MRVGridLoad(MIVP);
            //MRVMIVAccordion.SelectedIndex = 0;
            fp_GridViewSource(gvMRVdetails, DTMRVdetails);
        }
    }
```

I can't understand what is the cause of this problem.Is any body?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually running your stored procedure in SQL to see how long it takes to execute? It could be that there is no problem with the piece of code you have shown but rather simply that the procedure is taking longer than your timeouts allow.

Consider increasing how long timeouts are allowed for. This can be done in your web.config file and also on IIS (if you are using ISS for hosting your website). I would provide more details on this but you haven't specified what sort of timeout exception you are getting... Is it a page request timeout or a database timeout?

Ultimately if your stored procedure is to blame then perhaps it needs rethought. Hopefully it is just a simple coding issue and you don't have bigger server issues!

Comment: When I remove the line 
                MIVP.CustomerID = -1;(Left to using its previous value) time out not happen.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a loop? Have you stepped through the code? Perhaps the gridview loading is being recursively called. What is the exact exception being thrown?